# Rails 3.1 - Strange Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm getting the following on Heroku but not locally, seems pretty strange, any ideas?

```
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass):
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <h3>Product Tracklisting</h3>
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:    <ol id="track-list" data-update-url=<%= sort_producttracklistings_url %>>
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:    <% @product.producttracklistings.sort_by { |producttracklisting| producttracklisting.position }.each  do |products_track| %>
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <%= content_tag_for :li, products_track do %>
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: 
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/_tracklisting.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_products__tracklisting_html_erb___857430611_70068520180420'
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_products_show_html_erb___556626077_70068514945180'
2012-05-22T11:49:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:91:in `show'
```

I thought it could have been because `data-update-url=<%= sort_producttracklistings_url %>` was previously `data-update-url="<%= sort_producttracklistings_url %>"` but that made no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from `@product.producttracklistings.sort_by { |producttracklisting| producttracklisting.position }.each` (line 4).

Does each `producttracklisting` have a `position`?

The `<=>` is a general comparison operator used in sorting to return either `-1`, `0` or `+1` depending on whether it's receiver is less than, equal to, or greater than it's argument.

Comment: Ah ha!! I looked in SQL console and you're right, some positions on older products were missing. I manually set these and it now works!

Answer (score 1):

Its in the line

```
<% @product.producttracklistings.sort_by { |producttracklisting| producttracklisting.position }.each  do |products_track| %>
```

And due to some of the `producttracklisting` have `position` as `nil`.